# How to sort network devices with VLANs by numeric order

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I'm trying to create a neat and tidy motd for some embedded devices that will have multiple NICs and VLANs.

Here's a sample output:

```
Networking      sent  recv tx-err rx-err address
enp7s0     UP   66K   154     0     0   10.10.0.4
enp7s0.10  UP     0    17     0     0   10.1.10.4
enp7s0.2   UP     0    17     0     0   10.1.2.1
enp7s0.3   UP     0    17     0     0   10.1.3.4
tun0       UP     0    17     0     0   10.x.x.x
```

I'd like the above output to have enp7s0.10 as the last item. Like so:

```
enp7s0     UP   66K   154     0     0   10.10.0.4
enp7s0.2   UP     0    17     0     0   10.1.2.1
enp7s0.3   UP     0    17     0     0   10.1.3.4
enp7s0.10  UP     0    17     0     0   10.1.10.4
tun0       UP     0    17     0     0   10.x.x.x
```

I've tried sorting the output using `sort -t "." -n -k 2`, and while it's close, it doesn't quite do what is needed here. What I really need is a two tier sort: sort first by prefixes (i.e. everything to the left of the "."), then sort by suffixes.

I'm struggling to do this in pure bash. I want to avoid spinning up perl or python to get this done (since the hardware I'm running is CPU light), and would rather live with the minor aggravation of not being able to clean it up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "version sort" `sort -V` if your version of 'sort' has this feature.

There is also a `natsort` tool written in C, I *think* its new location is https://github.com/sourcefrog/natsort

I wouldn't avoid Perl, a fully self-contained Perl (or even PHP) script can often do the job faster than a shell script that invokes a ton of greps and seds and other external tools.

Comment: Amazing. I thought I'd scrutinized every flag of sort, but evidently I didn't. 

Thanks for the answer.